# Equivalent of Get-Device in 2016 windows

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there an equivalent powershell command of Get-device in 2016 Windows ?I need to list all the motherboard slots and the name of the devices that occupy them, if any. To be specific  i want to find out all the disks connected, disks connected directly , and through PCIe slots  etc .

Comment: Are you talking about Get-CMDevice by chance. Otherwise educate us what you mean precisely.  Are you talking about a Powershell cmdlet?  Which version of Windows are you using exactly.  Edit your question. As currently written your question will be next to impossible to answer

Comment: Sorry that my question was not detailed enough , I was looking at this article and trying to use the command Get -Device in this article -https://superuser.com/questions/1146392/powershell-pci-pcie-slot-occupation .

Comment: But i did not find the command Get-device in windows 2016 .So was checking if there is an equivalent one for windows 2016.

Comment: Yes, i am looking for an equivalent powershell cmdlet .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “Windows 2016” do you mean Windows **Server** 2016?  Why did you ignore my request for you to clarify your question by editing it?   Why can’t you use Get-Device, if it worked on an earlier version of PowerShell, it should still work with the current version.  **Edit** your question, do not, reply with a comment

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent powershell command of Get-device in 2016 Windows?

I assume you mean Windows Server 2016.  Just install the [Device Management PowerShell cmdlets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-Device` cmdlet used there comes from a nonstandard PowerShell module: [Device Management PowerShell Cmdlets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/). ([A comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1146392/powershell-pci-pcie-slot-occupation#comment1647611_1146392) on that question refers to [this TechNet blog article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/) with some background and motivation for the module.) To use the module, including this cmdlet, follow the installation instructions from the download page:

> - Download the DeviceManagement.zip file and save to a folder of your choice
> - Unblock the .zip file by using the Unblock-File cmdlet or Windows Explorer (Right click, Properties, “Unblock”)
> - Extract the archive contents
> - Launch PowerShell, navigate to the folder the archive contents were extracted to
> - Execute the below command:
>
>   ```
>   Import-Module .\DeviceManagement.psd1 -Verbose
>   ```

It should be fine to leave off the `-Verbose` switch. Once that's finished, you'll be able to use the cmdlets it provides.

If you want to have the cmdlets available all the time to all users, you need to [install the module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx). Rename the `Release` folder to `DeviceManagement` and copy it into this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

Restart PowerShell if it was running and the module will be ready to go.